# Why is ajax submitting multiple times?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Ajax in order to submit form data for logging in.

```
<form action="/Account/Login" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#loginSection" method="post">                                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
```

It works fine on the first post.  However, when the user click the button a second time, 3 ajax posts occur.  Then 8 times and so on.  At first I thought it was because the Submit button was getting replaced, so I took it out of the "loginSection"  But the same behavior is occurring.

So why is this occurring and what do I need to change? It makes no sense to me.

Here is the full LoginPartial with the ajax:

```
@model NTC.PropertySearch.Models.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "loginSection", }))
                        {
                             @Html.Partial("_LoginInfoPartial", Model) 
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />

                        }
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: sounds like submit handler is being called after some event , ajax load, button click, submit event itself etc. Adding new handler on top of existing one will compound the handlers. Need to see more code

Comment: Is it possible there are too many references to the JScript libraries?  Would that cause such an issue?

Comment: so what gets sent back to fill the target? I'm betting it includes the `unobtrusive-ajax` script again

Comment: This might not matter, but I noticed you are referencing a "jqueryval" script bundle, as well as an unobtrusive-ajax.js file. Were these added into the existing script bundles? Most MVC4 projects already have a lot of this functionality baked in right out of the box, so you might have duplicate libraries.

Comment: Josh, yes, I took that out as well and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl, you are right.  It did, and when I removed it, everything works ok now.